# Vue: How to implement extended functionality of generated divs by placing them into an array?

Tags: html, vue.js

I am using Vue to create a web app in which it is possible to create new divs (one at the time) with a button click. It is also possible to minimize these divs. It's isn't these divs that are changing size, but it needs to be this way because of functionality I cant reveal here. You can visit this jsFiddle to see it in action: **[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/acfmcr3L/)**.

If you click on the Increase button it will be possible to increase the limitation of divs that it is possible to generate on the website. If you click on the button the div will "change size".

There are some limitations though that I haven't been able to solve yet. The most important issue is that I want it to be possible to change the size of the divs, on at the time. How do I do that? It must be possible to handle several divs this way.

I have thought of placing them in an array like you can find in this: **[example](http://%20https://codepen.io/jacobgoh101/pen/QQYaZv?editors=1010)**. I think that it would also help me target some selected "small" divs for other functions with help of the index. In one case in need to select all minimized divs but the first one. Is an array the best way to get the functionality I have revealed?

Here is my progress so far... This code is not working in its present shape. The goal is to make it have the same functionality as in the codePen **example**, but still be able to the same things as the code in the **jsFiddle**.

If you prefer, visit this **[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/20k398zy/)** in which you can find this code:

**HTML**

```
<div id="lotsOfDivs">
    <addingdivs></addingdivs>
</div>
```

**Vue.js**

```
var gate = 0; // This global variable is used to increase the limitation of divs to be generated.

var expArray=[];   //The array where I want to place the "small divs"

$(document).ready(function(){

$(".expandable").each(function(){ displayDiv.push($(this));});
});    

Vue.component('addingdivs', {
    template: `
<div>
    <div id="header">
        <button class="addDiv" type="button" @click="createDiv">ADD LOCATION</button>
    </div>
    <div id=parent v-for="n in count" :style="{ 'height': height}">
        <div id="big" v-for="(item, i) in displayDiv" v-if="expand(i)>
            <div class="firstChild">
                <button class="done" @click="increaseLimit">INCREASE</button>
            </div>
            <div class="secondChild">
                <button class="done" @click="expand">EXPAND</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="smal" v-for="(item, i) in displayDiv" v-if="expand(i)">
            <button class="done" @click="expand">EXPAND</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
    `,
 data: function() {
        return {
            displayDiv: [false],
            gate: gate,
            height: "",
            count: 0,
             i:0,
         }
    },

    methods: {
        expand: function() {
            this.$set(this.displayDiv, i, !this.displayDiv[i]);

            if (!this.displayDiv) {
                this.height = '7vh';
            }
            else {
                this.height = "";
            }
        },

        createDiv: function() {

            if (this.count <= gate) {   // Here you can decide how many divs that will be generated

                this.count++;    
            }
        },

        increaseLimit: function() {
// Here you can increase the number of divs that it's possible to generate
            gate++;

        }
    }
});

new Vue({

    el: '#lotsOfDivs',
});
```

**CSS**

```
body {
    background: #20262E;
    padding: 20px;
    font-family: Helvetica;
}

#header {
    background: #30BFB7;
    border-radius: 4px;
    padding: 20px;
    transition: all 0.2s;
    height: 2vh;
    margin-bottom: 2vh
}

#big {
    background: #207F7A;
    border-radius: 4px;
    padding: 20px;
    transition: all 0.2s;
    height: 20vh;
    margin-bottom: 2vh
}

#smal {
    background: #10403D;
    border-radius: 4px;
    padding: 20px;
    transition: all 0.2s;
    height: 2vh;
    padding-bottom: 2vh;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Linus Borg at Vue.js forum posted a solution to this question! [Click here to go to see the solution](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/how-to-implement-extended-functionality-of-generated-divs-by-placing-them-into-an-array/34875/2)!

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass $event into the function expand. And then in the function get the clicked elements parent. 
Here is a working fiddle link:
https://jsfiddle.net/wwf8nwsg/15/

```
var gate = 0;

Vue.component('addingdivs', {
  template: `
<div>
    <div id="header">
        <button class="addDiv" type="button" @click="createDiv">ADD LOCATION</button>
        <button class="done" @click="increaseLimit">INCREASE</button> 
    </div>
    <div class="big" v-for="n in count" :style="{ 'height': height}">              
            <button class="done" @click="expand($event)">Small</button>  
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
    `,
  data: function() {
    return {
      displayDiv: [false],
      gate: gate,
      height: "",
      count: 0,
      locationsArr: ["one", "two", "three"],
    }
  },

  methods: {
    expand: function(e) {
      console.log(e);
      console.log(e.originalTarget.parentElement.className);

      if (e.originalTarget.parentElement.className == 'big') {
        e.originalTarget.parentElement.className = 'small';
        e.originalTarget.innerText = 'Big';
      } else {
        e.originalTarget.parentElement.className = 'big'
        e.originalTarget.innerText = 'Small';
      }
    },

    createDiv: function() {

      if (this.count <= gate) { // Here you can decide how many divs that will be generated

        this.count++;

      }
    },

    increaseLimit: function() {
      // Here you can increase the number of divs that it's possible to generate
      gate++;

    }
  }
});

new Vue({

  el: '#lotsOfDivs',
});
```